# Redis how to assign multiple values?

Tags: redis, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How to assign multiple values ​​to one key? I need to import a key into Jmeter that will contain many values.

Comment: You can try Redis LIST and Redis HASH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your "multiple values" don't contain the [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) (default is comma) they will go into single [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

More information: [JMeter’s Redis Data Set - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction)